# How can I validate a citation that is genuine in google scholar but as a *?

Tags: citations, google-scholar

Google Scholar may mark citation counts with an asterisk (*), meaning:

> This "Cited by" count includes citations to the following articles in Scholar. The ones marked * may be different from the article in the profile.

How can I validate citations in my Google Scholar account that are genuine but are marked with a *?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just open the different articles, search for your name and see the citations for yourself? Usually, this is quickly done. If some of the articles are not available at your institution, it may be harder.

Answer (score 1):

The asteriks appears after merging two (or more) articles in a Google Scholar profile.

The asterisk (*) shows up on the profile next to the merged items because variations of the same publication are present in their database (this is because of an error in page numbers, misspelling of an author name and so on).

You can be pretty sure that it is a genuine citation.

Answer (score 0):

I edited the question to explain the meaning of asterisks, but perhaps that's an answer in itself: Google doesn't know whether it has correctly counted citations, in particular, it is unsure about those marked  with an asterisk.

Comment: @Mick Why does it not? Would you like me to explicitly add: _So, you can't_? I left this implicit, because it seemed to follow naturally

Comment: My bad, I read the first line and misread the second line. I will delete the previous comment.